# Python 3, TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, api

```
async def chuck(self):
        joketype = 'nerdy' if randint(0, 100) < 50 else 'explicit'
        cnjoke = requests.get('http://api.predator.wtf/joke/?arguments={}'.format(joketype),allow_redirects = True).content

        return '{}'.format(str(cnjoke.replace('&quot;', '"').replace('steal', 'steel')))
```

I am trying to use this api to get chuck norris jokes (don't ask lol) but it is returning this error:

````
return '```{}```'.format(str(cnjoke.replace('&quot;', '"').replace('steal', 'steel')))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
````

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
'```{}```'.format(str(cnjoke).replace('&quot;', '"').replace('steal', 'steel'))
````

or

````
'```{}```'.format(cnjoke.decode().replace('&quot;', '"').replace('steal', 'steel'))
````

and `content` returns bytes

```
type(cnjoke) #bytes
```

using `text` instead may be better in your case

```
_cnjoke = requests.get('http://api.predator.wtf/joke/?arguments={}'.format(joketype),allow_redirects = True).text
type(_cnjoke) #str
```